# Backbone: Best way to handle large amounts of view listeners?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle the following situation. Imagine we have a collection of records that will each be attached to a view. Each view will have a button that runs particular functionality. For arguments sake, there could be up to one hundred of these views on the page at once. An example of this view would be below:

```
var RecordView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .js-cta': 'onCTAClick'
    },
    onCTAClick: function(event) {
        // Do something.
    }
});
```

This obviously would bind 100 DOM Listeners and take up much more memory than we'd like. One way of handling this would be to have a View for the Collection, and put a single delegated listener at that level, which would determine what view should be notified, and then trigger an event, like so:

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.Extend({
    events: {
        'click .js-cta': 'onCTAClick'
    },
    onCTAClick: function(event) {
        // Use event data to determine appropriate child view to notify.
        // Notify the child view by triggering an event on it (childView.trigger('CTAClick')).
    }
});

var RecordView = Backbone.View.Extend({
    initialise: function() {
        this.on('CTAClick', this.onCTAClick);
    },
    onCTAClick: function(event) {
        // Use event data to determine appropriate child view to notify.
        // Notify the child view by triggering an event on it (childView.trigger('')).
    }
});
```

I wonder if this is any better than the 100+ DOM listener method... You'd only have one DOM listener, but then 100 listeners in the RecordView waiting to be notified of the event. Are DOM event listeners "heavier" than Backbone event listeners? You could remove the listeners entirely and have the CollectionView directly trigger a method, reducing listeners to a single one, but this tightly couples the views. Does this tight coupling matter though if these two views are so close in function and are almost interwoven anyway?

What is the correct way of approaching this situation?

Comment: Are you noticing performance issues? 100 event listeners doesn't seem like very much.

Comment: I'm not but it's the concept in general I'm more interested in; how to handle a multitude of DOM events in Backbone that conceptually should/could be handled with much fewer listeners (delegation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMOH I don't think there is a correct way. Both approaches you outline work. However when dealing with a lot of views, the delegated method leveraging DOM bubbling would be optimal from a memory perspective. In this approach I would probably be inclined to store an id of the record view in the record view DOM as a data attribute, and store a map of the view against this id in the collection view. Then just call the method directly. Wouldn't worry about it being tightly coupled.

Comment: I sort of lean to this method myself. I don't see the point in keeping it "loosely" coupled with each view attaching a listener to itself, just so the parent view can trigger it.

One delegated listener on the parent directly calling the required method on the child views sounds the most performant!